# Puppeteer get window URL through page redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

In Puppeteer I'm trying to get the current URL of the page I'm on, however, when the page changes my `setInterval` doesn't pick up the new URL of the new page, for example, the URL journey looks like:

1. https://example.com/
2. https://google.com/ <- redirects after X seconds

I expect to see https://example.com/ listed in the `console.log`, which I do, but after navigating to a new URL I only ever see the original URL.

What am I missing from my code here?

```js
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(argv.url); // <-- the page I go to has some auto-redirects
  const currentUrl = () => {
    return window.location.href;
  }

  let data = await page.evaluate(currentUrl);
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`current URL is: ${data}`);
  }, 250)

  // await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function each time (currently you just output the same static result of one past call):

```js
  setInterval(async () => {
    console.log(`current URL is: ${await page.evaluate(currentUrl)}`);
  }, 250)
```